# How to lazy trigger cascade with hidden form element on ngx-formly

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

In [ngx-formly](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly), the [cascading example](https://formly.dev/examples/other/cascaded-select) has these cascading `select` shown by default. So the hooks to initializing the observers work.

In my case, I have more complex design. I want to hide those selects and show them based on user opt-in.

But this way, `sportControl` form control is null when the form are initialized. These observers on `valueChanges` cannot be set.

```
hooks: {
        onInit: field => {
          ...
          const sportControl = this.form.get('sport');
          field.templateOptions.options = sportControl.valueChanges.pipe(
           ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `hideExpression` to control the visibility of each base baed on model value or some external expression here is a starting example:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxpbyc?file=src/app/app.component.ts